# Upgrade to php 7 and apache 2.4 from php 5.3 and apache 2.2 in Amazon EC2

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, php-7, rhel, apache2.4

I have a legacy system in which **Apache 2.2.34 (linux)** is installed along with **php 5.3.29 (CLI).**

I just want to upgrade my apache to 2.4.x so that I will be able to use php 7.

I have tried searching for the same but majority of sites provide solution for CentOS or Ubuntu. I'm new to Linux so I'm a bit confused when applying the same on **Amazon EC2 instance.**

That would be really helpful if someone can provide me a step by step process to do the upgrade process. I just need to upgrade the server and I can do the configuration accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more googling, I have found the steps I have taken to upgrade. Hope that helps anyone looking for the same:

Login to your Linux instance and perform the regular system updates first

```
$ sudo yum update
```

Stop the running web server

```
$ sudo service httpd stop
```

Create backup of the existing httpd by using command:

```
$ sudo cp -a /etc/httpd /etc/httpd.bak
```

Remove any existing PHP packages

```
$ sudo yum remove php*
```

Remove old web server installs

```
$ sudo yum remove httpd*
```

Update yum package repository

```
$ sudo yum clean all
$ sudo yum upgrade -y
```

Install Apache 2.4

```
$ sudo yum install httpd24
```

Install PHP 7 packages

```
$ sudo yum install php70 php70-mysqlnd php70-imap php70-pecl-memcache php70-pecl-apcu php70-gd
```

Install a new version of mod_ssl

```
$ sudo yum install mod24_ssl
```

**I also needed to reconfigure /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf and /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf in order to enable SSL and pretty permalinks.**

Finally all I needed to do is start my web server

```
$ service httpd start
```

That's it.

Answer (score -1):

Do retain that the solution by MrGoogle will reset any configuration in existence in the hpptd service.
You will probably need to reconfigure some settings...
I had to reconfigure mod_rewrite and .htaccess File for apache:
https://devops.ionos.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-centos-7/